# How to filter Core Data by entities not in relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I have an NSManagedObject SchoolClass that has a To Many relationship to Students.  I have it working for when I want to find SchoolClasses containing a specified student by using,

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY students == %@)", student];
```

How would I set up an NSPredicate to return an NSArray of SchoolClasses that do NOT contain a specified student?  I thought something like below would work but it does not.

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(NONE students IN %@)", student];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN` is used when the right-hand side is a collection, such as an array of students. Try this predicate instead:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(NONE students = %@)", student];
```

This is also equivalent to `ALL students != %@`.

This will only return SchoolClasses who do not include the specified student.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I believe it correctly answers my question as I have asked it. I made the mistake of simplifying my NSPredicate example for this question, so unfortunately for my more complicated logic (which I did not present in this question), it's not working as expected.  Also, if I try, @"(ALL students != %@)"... it crashes with an, 'Unsupported predicate (null)' message.  I will open another question with the full NSPredicate logic I am trying to filter.